# React rendering in a loop stops after first element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am rendering multiple divs using the class but I see only the first div rendered.

```
<html> 
<body> 
  <div class="elem" name="foo"/>
  <div class="elem" name="bar"/>
  <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class MyElement extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>NAME: {this.props.name}</div>
    }
}

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div, index) {
    render(<MyElement name={div.getAttribute('name')}/>, div);
});
```

I only see "NAME: foo" but no "NAME: bar". I even tried adding "key={index}" to  element but no use.

Here are the dependencies used:

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "webpack": "^2.2.1"
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to create multiple react apps in a loop like that?

Comment: @spirift -- App may be confusing - I changed it to "MyElement".. Yes I need to render multiples of MyElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs should define with start and end tags.

```
<div class="app" name="foo"></div>
<div class="app" name="bar"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as the correct answer. :)